# How to add xml layout(setContentView()) of another app(skin) to main app?

Tags: android, themes, skins

Suppose in my main app i have a layout "main_layout.xml" and in my skin(another app) app i have a layout "main_layout2.xml" .

Now how can i set `setContentView(main_layout2)` in my main app if skin app is installed and if not installed then `setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);`

i know this much:

```
[In Theme package] 
1. set action for activity, for example: my.package.theme 
2. add all files you need for this theme 

[In main app] 
  // Create intent with your action: my.package.theme 
  Intent intent = new Intent(); 
  intent.setAction("my.package.theme"); 

  // Get list of all installed packages with your themes 
  List<ResolveInfo> lresolve = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0); 

  int size = lresolve.size(); 
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { 
    ApplicationInfo appInfo = lresolve.get 
(i).activityInfo.applicationInfo; 
    try { 
      Resources resSkin = pm.getResourcesForApplication(appInfo); 
      int backres = resSkin.getIdentifier("my_background", "drawable", 
appInfo.packageName); 
      // getting background from theme package 
      Drawable background = resSkin.getDrawable(backres); 
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) { 
       e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
  }
```

By above code i can change the image . But how to infiltrate a xml layout of an other app to main app.

please help me in this (a sample code or example links, it would be appreciated).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Re-using Layouts with `<include/>` [Click here](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)

```
 <include layout="@layout/main_layout2"/>
```

Comment: Muraliganesan: main_layout2 is present in another app. then how can i use it in my main app